# No Exact match when using LIKE in SQL statement

Tags: sql, mysql

```
   SELECT bp.*,r.rating,COUNT(r.review_for),bp.business_name,bp.profile_member 
     FROM ibf_business_reviews r 
LEFT JOIN ibf_business_profiles bp ON ( r.review_for=bp.profile_member ) 
    WHERE bp.sub_category LIKE '%{$id},%'{$location_sql} 
 GROUP BY r.review_for HAVING COUNT(r.review_for) >=1 
 ORDER BY r.date_posted DESC LIMIT 0,2");
```

This query is used to show results for business_name in a certain sub_category id '%{$id} in a certain location. My problem is that extra results are showing in categories that share a second or third digit  aka ...viewcat&id=54 will show in ..viewcat&id=154 etc

I using the LIKE may be my issue? `WHERE bp.sub_category LIKE '%{$id},%'`

Comment: Hi @johnny-kessel ~ can you reformat that SQL, and can you verify the question is worded like you want? If I understand you, you want to know how to stop matching things like 154, but to ONLY match 54? Then use = instead of `LIKE`...

Comment: +! for the need to reformat the SQL.  You do realize that the "percent" signs (%) are the wildcards.  So you're essentially telling it that you can return ANYTHING that includes `id`... so if you search "23" you could get "123", you could get "234" or "1234"... etc.

Comment: Apologize for the formatting issue, I'll give that a shot Rock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was my comment

> +! for the need to reformat the SQL. You do realize that the "percent"
>   signs (%) are the wildcards. So you're
>   essentially telling it that you can
>   return ANYTHING that includes id... so
>   if you search "23" you could get
>   "123", you could get "234" or
>   "1234"... etc.

and you replied

> Thanks @Rock removing the wildcards worked!

Now my answer to this is... If you removed BOTH wildcards from your string, then you're essentially doing an "equals".

IE:

```
WHERE bp.sub_category LIKE '{$id},'
```

should be the same as

```
WHERE bp.sub_category = '{$id},'
```

Because you don't have any wildcards to "match" in the "LIKE" statement.

*Please forgive me if I screwed up the "$" or the ","... I'm not a MySQL guy*

Comment: Awesome thanks I'd vote your answer up but I don't have rep.. this is the accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

You are storing a comma-separated list in a varchar, when you should store one number per row in a child table.  Then you wouldn't have to use `LIKE` at all.

Read up on [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: Thanks Bill I somewhat inherited this data model but good advice.. I'd vote you up but I don't have the rep yet

Comment: Clever deduction... @OP: You might want to invest some time normalizing the DB if you have that power...even if someone dropped it on your lap.

Comment: Thanks @Mark ..I suppose it's the right thing to do so here goes my life for the weekend

Comment: @johnny: Shouldn't be *that* bad... just pull all the records out, split the IDs by commas, and re-insert them into the DB as separate rows... just make sure you think out the whole DB and all the tables before you start tackling it.